# Inverse of a linear map involving polynomial derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse, inverse-function

> Let $V = \bigl\{f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \mid \exists a_0,\dots,a_4\in \mathbb{R},\, f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{4}a_ix^i \bigr\}$, we define the linear map $\phi:V \rightarrow V$ as follows:
> $$
> \phi(f)(x)=f''(x)+xf'(x)-f(x+1).
> $$
> Find $\phi^{-1}(\{g\})$ where $g(x)=2x^3+1$.

I'm unsure of my solution to this problem and I need someone to help me. In a previous exercise I determined the transformation matrix as follows, but the problem is that the matrix is obviously not invertible.
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
-1&-1&1&-1&-1 \\ 
0&0&-2&3&-4 \\ 
0&0&1&-3&6 \\ 
0&0&0&2&-1 \\ 
0&0&0&0&3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So I was wondering if the answer is simply "$\phi^{-1}(g)(x)$ doesn't exist. "

Comment: In order to represent a linear transformation by a matrix, you have to specify a basis for the source and target (in this case, they're the same space so you probably intend to use the same basis for both). What is that basis, explicitly, including order? What are the coordinates of $g(x)$ with respect to that basis?

Comment: The problem is not asking you about $\phi^{-1}(g)(x)$, but about the *set* $\phi^{-1}(\{g\}) = \{f \in V : \phi(f)=g\}$. This is the [inverse image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image) of $\{g\}$ under $\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the standard monomial basis for $V$:
$$
\beta = \bigl\{ 1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4 \bigr\},
$$
so the columns of the matrix express the coefficients of the image of these basis vectors when expressed back in terms of the basis. Explicitly, for $0 \leq j \leq 4$, column $j$ expresses $\phi(x^j)$ as linear combination of the $x^i$:
$$
\phi(x^j) = \sum_{i=0}^4 a_{ij} x^i. 
$$

We're interested in the preimage of $g$ under this transformation, denoted
$$
\phi^{-1}(g) = \bigl\{f \in V \mid \phi(f) = g \bigr\}. 
$$
This is a *set* of polynomials, each of which maps to $g$ under the transformation $\phi$.

Let's express $g$ in coordinates with respect to the basis:
$$
g = 2x^3 + 1 = \color{red}{1} + \color{orange}{0}x + \color{green}{0}x^2 + \color{blue}{2}x^3 + \color{purple}{0}x^4 
\quad\implies\quad 
\bigl(g\bigr)_\beta 
= \begin{pmatrix} 
\color{red}{1} \\ 
\color{orange}{0} \\ 
\color{green}{0} \\ 
\color{blue}{2} \\ 
\color{purple}{0} 
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$
So we want to solve the linear system
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
-1&-1&1&-1&-1 \\ 
0&0&-2&3&-4 \\ 
0&0&1&-3&6 \\ 
0&0&0&2&-4 \\ 
0&0&0&0&3
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \\ a_4 
\end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$
Note that $a_{3, 4} = -4$, which differs from your calculation, although it doesn't change the conclusion. We can express this matrix-vector equation as the augmented matrix
$$
\left( 
\begin{matrix} 
-1&-1&1&-1&-1 \\ 
0&0&-2&3&-4 \\ 
0&0&1&-3&6 \\ 
0&0&0&2&-4 \\ 
0&0&0&0&3
\end{matrix}  
\;\; \middle| \;\; 
\begin{matrix} 
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 
\end{matrix}
\right). 
$$
Unfortunately, a few row operations show that the system is inconsistent, i.e. that there are no solutions. Hence,
$$
\phi^{-1}(g) = \varnothing. 
$$
This preimage set always *exists*. It just happens to be empty.